# Divide a column of a dataframe by a slice of another column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with three columns: one for identification, one with the main variable and one with some values that will serve to make computations on the second one. I would like to divide the second by the third, but this third column only has values on one slice.

Maybe an example will be clearer:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"),
                 y = c(2, 4, NA, 6, 6, 7),
                 z = c(NA, NA, NA, 8, 5, 3))
```

Here's the expected result:

```
df_expected <- data.frame(x = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"),
                          y = c(2/8, 4/5, NA, 6/8, 6/5, 7/3),
                          z = c(NA, NA, NA, 8, 5, 3))
```

As you can see, I would like to group observations by the id column `x` and then divide column `y` by column `z`.

This is what I've done so far:

```
library(dplyr)

computation <- function(t){
  df$t <- ifelse(df$z == NA, NA, df$t/df$z)
}

df %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  mutate_at(c("y"), .funs = computation)
```

but I have the error:

> `` Erreur : Column `y` must be length 2 (the group size) or one, not 6 ``

How can I do that?
I'm almost sure that my question has already been asked and that it is quite simple but I can't figure out how to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(x) %>% mutate(yz=y/z[!is.na(z)])
```

Use `first(z[!is.na(z)])` in case you have more than one slice of values.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your "slice" is defined somewhere. Then you can just use ordinary division, the three valid `z` values will be recycled.

```
defSlice <- 4:6
DT.tr <- transform(DT, y=y / z[defSlice])

DT.tr
#   x        y  z
# 1 A 0.250000 NA
# 2 B 0.800000 NA
# 3 C       NA NA
# 4 A 0.750000  8
# 5 B 1.200000  5
# 6 C 2.333333  3
```